# Randomize or not the order of items?

Tags: experiment-design

(*It is a question about an optimal design, rather than a statistical question. So if it's not allowed by the rules, I am sorry in advance: please don't downvote me, but just let me know and I'll delete the question*)

So simplifying things as much as possible:
I want to measure whether information about crime rate affects the preferences towards a region. To do this in between-subject design I let participants choose between Region 1, and Region 2, providing them several pieces of information. In a control treatment these pieces **do not** include crime rate. In a T_A, these pieces **do** include crime rate. Other pieces of information are the same in both treatments.

So schematically it looks like that:

[image: treatmentexample]

So, the hypothesis is that in T_A the share of those who prefer R1 to R2 will be higher than in the baseline.

The question is:

- should I randomize the order of Regions between subjects? (so sometimes Region 1 goes first, sometimes Region 2 goes first).
- should I randomize the order of pieces of information between subjects? (so sometimes the information is shown in order Population->Crime rate->Average wage, and sometimes Crime rate->Average wage->Population etc.)
- If I do both or one of randomizations, does it substantially increase the sample size?

Comment: Randomizing does not affect the sample size. I would randomize both, it doesn't hurt and doesn't make your results any less powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anchoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring_(cognitive_bias)) may make your participants decide differently on the second item they see *because of what they saw in the first item*. The simplest way to reduce this effect (more precisely, to balance it across participants) is indeed to randomize the order.

Also: it's much easier to randomize before you start the experiment... than to rebut a reviewer who complains about the lack of randomization because of a possible anchoring effect (or other bias).

So: yes, do randomize. Especially the order of regions. Possibly also the order of information shown, but that may confuse your participants, so the benefit is less clear-cut here.

As [user2974951 points out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/550763/randomize-or-not-the-order-of-items#comment1012094_550763), there are no sample size implications. Or if there are, they would go the other way: if you do *not* randomize but account for possible sequence or anchoring effects in your model, you will likely need a larger sample size than if you simply randomize.

Comment: great, thanks a lot! I'll follow your advice. Quick follow-up question (perhaps it's worth to ask in a separate post, let me know). What is more clean design-wise in your opinion: to *replace* some piece of information in the list with the **crime-rate** (which is the focus of the study), or to *add* it to the list? (when we add, we control for amount of information available to a person _in addition_ to the crime rate; when we replace, we control for the total volume (length of the list) of the information available when they make a decision).

Comment: I don't think that would be a question of study *design*. Rather, it's a question of what scientific question your study is addressing. So I would say it's better to decide based on your theory and your scientific goals, rather than in terms of experiment design.